# Returning custom data structure from C++ via NIF

Tags: c++, erlang, elixir, ffi

I have a C++ function which I want to export via NIF.  It accepts and operates with custom data structures, `std::vectors` and the like.

I'm confused about what sequence of steps should be to convert Elixir type into C++ and back.

I'm aware about `enif_make_resource()`, `enif_release_resource()` and `enif_open_resource_type()`

Do they have to be used when returning data? Or only when parsing incoming parameters?

Code, partly:

```
static int nif_load(ErlNifEnv* env, void** priv_data, ERL_NIF_TERM load_info) {
  ErlNifResourceType* rt = enif_open_resource_type(env, nullptr, "vector_of_my_struct_s1",
    vec1_dtor, ERL_NIF_RT_CREATE, nullptr);

  if (rt == nullptr) {
    return -1;
  }

  assert(vec1_res == nullptr);
  vec1_res = rt;
  return 0;
}

ERL_NIF_INIT(Elixir.MyApp, nif_funcs, nif_load, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

And function:

```
ERL_NIF_TERM do_cpp_calculations_nif(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[]) {
  // [........for now, parsing incoming arguments is skipped...]


  std::vector<MyStructS1> native_res1 = do_cpp_calculations1(....);


  ERL_NIF_TERM term;

  // how to return 'native_res1' ?

  // do I have to I use these functions at all?

  // enif_alloc_resource(...) ?
  // enif_make_resource(..)  ?

  // and how?

  return term;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In [the doc](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#resource_objects) and [this module from the official repo](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/example/matrix_nif.c) you have examples on how to do it.

Usually the steps you need are:

1. Create empty resource
2. Operate with the resource

Sometimes you do both in the same function.

**Create empty resource:**

Example from [the doc](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#resource_objects):

```c
    ERL_NIF_TERM term;
    MyStruct* obj = enif_alloc_resource(my_resource_type, sizeof(MyStruct));
    
    /* initialize struct ... */
    
    term = enif_make_resource(env, obj);
    
    if (keep_a_reference_of_our_own) {
        /* store 'obj' in static variable, private data or other resource object */
    }
    else {
        enif_release_resource(obj);
        /* resource now only owned by "Erlang" */
    }
    return term;
```

I'd recommend releasing the resource immediately and relying on the GC for the destructor, which should free the vector memory (you should make `std::vector` use `enif_alloc` to manage the memory), so in the end you may have something along the lines of:

```c
    static ERL_NIF_TERM create(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
    {
        void* pointer_to_resource_memory = enif_alloc_resource(vec1_res, sizeof(ResourceStruct));
        // TODO Initialize the resource memory
        ERL_NIF_TERM ret = enif_make_resource(env, pointer_to_resource_memory);
        enif_release_resource(pointer_to_resource_memory);
        return ret;
    
    }
```

**Operate with the resource**

In order to work with it, you only need to extract the pointer from the resource:

```c
static ERL_NIF_TERM do_stuff(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    void* pointer_to_resource_memory = NULL;
    if (!enif_get_resource(env, argv[0], vec1_res, &pointer_to_resource_memory) {
        return enif_make_badarg(env);
    }
    // TODO do stuff with the resource memory

    // TODO make a term and return it, no need to create a new resource
    return enif_make_int(env, 0);
}
```

Keep in mind that you don't need to create a new resource nor return it again if you don't want to, you're modifying the memory pointed by it.

**Wrapping a `std:vector` in a resource**

You may have noticed that in the snippets above I used only 'resource' and not 'vector', you have a choice there (my C++ is a bit rusty, though, so take the following with a grain of salt):

You can have the resource hold a pointer to the vector (safest):

```c
typedef struct {
   std::vector<MyStructS1>* vector; 
} ResourceStruct;

void* pointer_to_resource_memory = enif_alloc_resource(vec1_res, sizeof(ResourceStruct));
pointer_to_resource_memory->vector = new std::vector(...) // std::vector constructor is called here
// TODO 'new' should use enif_alloc(), destroy, enif_free()
```

or you can have the resource be the vector (I'm not sure if this syntax is allowed, but you get the idea):

```c
void* pointer_to_vector_object_memory = enif_alloc_resource(vec1_res, sizeof(std::vector<MyStructS1>));
// TODO: Somehow initialize a std::vector in the given memory
```

Comment: why wrap a vector into a struct? How to work with vector directly?

Comment: I've see  documentation and it's complicated there. In my code there's a single `do_cpp_calculations_nif()` function-wrapper only.

Comment: To work with the vector directly you'd need to have the resource BE the vector, and for that you'll need to be able to initialize a `std::vector` with pre-allocated memory (the one given by the enif_alloc_resource), I'm not knowledgeable enough with std::vectors to say how easy/complicated that is.

Comment: You can do both things in the same function, I just separated it because it's easier to explain

Comment: There're 5 pieces of code in your answer. Which ones should I use? In what order?

Comment: 2 and 3, in that order. Choose between 4 or 5 to use everywhere

Comment: 2 and 3 are separate functions. What and how `create()` called by? That's not shown in your example. My question is way simpler: I have only **1 function** -- `do_cpp_calculations_nif()` My question is only about it. I don't need all the the things I could do "if this", "if that". I need only a simple example with only mandatory stuff only for `do_cpp_calculations_nif()`. What will that be?